# Regex Contains No Capture Groups?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've got a series of malformed JSON data that I need to use Regex to get the data I need out of it, then I need to use regex again to remove a specific aspect of the data i.e. the main category, in the example below it's 'games'.

Part 1 works, the second part does not.

I've limited experience with Python, and next to no experience with Regex.

**Final Output**: games

I'm getting the error:

> ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups

The series of data contains information formated like this:

```
 {"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/games/playing%20cards"}},"color":51627,"parent_id":12,"name":"Playing Cards","id":273,"position":4,"slug":"games/playing cards"}
```

The Python call I'm using is this:

First I remove the slug from the JSON.

```
ksdata.cat_slug_raw = ksdata.category.str.extract('\"slug\"\:\"(.+?)\"', expand=False)
```

Then I remove everything before the /

```
ksdata.cat_slug = ksdata.cat_slug_raw.str.extract('^[^/]+(?=/)', expand=False)
```

I'd really appreciate some help with where I'm going wrong...and if you think my solution as a whole sux please tell me :)

Comment: Why do you say that's malformed JSON data? It looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're using to read the data in, but you may be able to use split `ksdata.cat_slug_raw.str.split('/')[0]` to split on the slash and take the first part.

Comment: @Vinny the word 'games'. When I use the regex tester I get the result I'm looking for, when I stick it in Python it doesn't work.

Comment: For one thing, I recommend using raw strings (prepend `r` in front of the string, e.g. `r'^[^/]+(?=/)'`) to avoid needing to escape special characters. I just find that throwing a ton of escape characters into my regex makes it easier to mess it up.

Comment: @TomSitter i'm using pandas. Would split only give me the output 'games'? or would it give me two outputs?

Comment: @PM2Ring just did. Thanks :)

Comment: Split gives you a list of items e.g. ['games', 'playing_cards'], indexing at [0] gives you the first item

Comment: @TomSitter got a key value error 0 when I ran this. It worked when I removed the key value.

Comment: @TomSitter used ksdata.cat_slug_raw.str.split('/').str[0] instead of
ksdata.cat_slug_raw.str.split('/')[0] Looks to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an amended suggestion from TomSitter I used

```
ksdata.cat_slug_raw.str.split('/').str[0]
```

This was the simplest way to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
s = '{"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/games/playing%20cards"}},"color":51627,"parent_id":12,"name":"Playing Cards","id":273,"position":4,"slug":"games/playing cards"}'
import ast
final_data = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Playing Cards', 'color': 51627, 'slug': 'games/playing cards', 'parent_id': 12, 'urls': {'web': {'discover': 'http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/games/playing%20cards'}}, 'position': 4, 'id': 273}
```

Comment: @NickDuddy `literal_eval()` processes the value as a Python literal, rather than JSON. This is more forgiving of some syntax problems, like using single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @NickDuddy `ast.literal_eval` is a more secure form of the builtin function `eval`. `ast.literal_eval`  forces the string you pass it to be interpreted, thus having your python code run code.

Comment: OK. I've never see this before so I'll give it a go and feedback. Sounds like a nice work around.

Comment: What? Saying `ast.literal_eval` runs code, is rather misleading: it can only parse strings that represent valid Python literals.